# Play Song continously

Tags: android, playback

I am working on a Music Application , Where I have recorded certain audio files,
I can Play the song individually but I have a button Play all on which I need to play all the Song present in that particular folder

Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve the task

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Create a list of all the songs in the folder and when the current song is about to end, start paying another until list reaches to its last song.

Comment: Hi I have tried this stuff but my loop is position is not increasing in OnCompletion

Comment: you need to post your code.

Comment: Got the answer thanks rohit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello Guys I Got the answer to my question finally

Please check the below code:

```
   public class ShowAllRecords extends ListActivity {
    private File file;
    private List<String> myList;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ListView listv;
    int currentposition = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        listv = getListView();
        listv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.musicapp);
        String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        file = new File(root_sd + "/mymusicapp/");
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            myList.add(list[j].getName());
        }

        listv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));

    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        File temp_file = new File(file, myList.get(position));

        if (!temp_file.isFile()) {
            file = new File(file, myList.get(position));
            File list[] = file.listFiles();

            myList.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                myList.add(list[i].getName());
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            //+l.getAdapter().getItem(position));
            listv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));
            playSong(file.toString() + "/" + myList.get(currentposition));


            l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    System.out.println("path is :--" + file.toString() + "/" + myList.get(position));

                }
            });
//
        }

    }

    private void playSong(String Songpath) {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(Songpath);
            mp.prepare();
            // mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();

            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Media Completed with Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println("In Oncompletion");
                    try {
                        currentposition++;
                        //   mediaPlayer.reset();
                        if (currentposition <=myList.size()) {

                            System.out.println("in if of postion");
                            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                            mediaPlayer.reset();
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.toString() + "/"+myList.get(currentposition));
                            System.out.println("FIle Path on Completion :--"+file.toString() + myList.get(currentposition));
                            mediaPlayer.prepare();
                            // mp.setLooping(true);
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }


                        // playSong(file.toString() + myList.get(currentposition));
                        System.out.println("path is :--" + file.toString() + currentposition);

                        //  nextSong();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the paths of all song in that folder in an arraylist (easy task).

Than add a oncompletionlistener() on your mediaplayer object.

And in that play another song as first song completes.

Easy task bro!